# Passing a variable into a class to determine which method to use

Tags: python, sqlite, class, methods

im not sure what im missing but it says that my class variable (var1) is not defined

```
Class Example(var1):
   if var1 ==1:
      def func1(var2)
         x = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM examples WHERE Name = 'var2' ")
         Return x
   else pass:

Example(1).func1("example")
```

could be because im tired and its simple but im also kinda new to this. Any help would be great and thank you

Comment: You're mixing class with function, replace your class with def

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `Class Example(var1):` means that you are creating a class, wich inherits from var1. If you want to define a function, use `def Example(var1):`

Answer (score 0):

Your Syntax is very messed up, lost of mistakes, but cleaned up it would look like this:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self,var1):
       if var1 ==1:
          def func1(var2):
             x = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM examples WHERE Name = 'var2' ")
             print(var2)
             return x
       else:
           pass

#Example(1).func1("example") you can not call 'func1'. At this point it doesnt exists!!

example = Example(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modular way of achieving the result,

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def func(self):
        if self.var == 1:
            return cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM examples WHERE Name = 'var1' ")
        elif self.var == 2:
            return cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM examples WHERE Name = 'var2' ")
        else:
            pass

ex = Example(1)
# call func which automatically executes query based on value of var
ex.func()
```